# Strange GAC behavior on server

Tags: .net

I'm noticing a strange behaviour with the GAC on our development server and also on my local machine. I signed an assembly and placed it in the GAC using an MSI file. When I run my application, it finds the assembly and loads it and the app runs ok.

As a test, I decided to remove the assembly from the GAC and rerun my application. Strangely enough the application still runs without telling me that the assembly cannot be found.

I made sure that the assembly is NOT in the bin folder of the application. I double-checked the GAC to make sure if it didn't really uninstall. It did really uninstall because the assembly is missing from the GAC folder. There is no trace of the assembly on the server except in a strange folder called c:\Windows\Assembly\temp\GPFPFRGYT. So why is my application still finding the assemby when I clearly see that it is no longer in the GAC (I'm using .NET 4.0 so that's in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would delete all copies of the dll including the one in the temp file you mentioned.

It's always worth unistalling GAC dll's by using:

GacUtil -u YourDLLFileName

Note: you do not have to use the extension .dll when using the above command with YourDLLFileName

I am not 100% sure you need to do this but I would also restart the server once the .dll have been unistalled.

I hope this helps

Comment: Once you install a DLL in the GAC using a windows Installer, you cannot uninstall it using gacutil.exe. It has to be uninstalled using the Windows Installer, which is what I did. Secondly, I don't have the option of restarting the server. Other developers are working.